# Having issue connecting to mysql db from excel macros

Tags: mysql, vba

I am having issue connecting to mysql in excel macro. I can pull the data manually but not from vba code.
Pease find snap shot of error and connection properties. Previously, it was working fine when connecting to MSSQL Db.

Thanks.

[Error 1004](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mv78s.png)

[Connection Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKRq6.png)

Comment: Please make a [reprex]. Include relevant code as text.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if any firewall blocks the standard MySQL port (3306). Does your MySQL user has the permission to connect to the database from remote machine?

Let me know

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this module](https://github.com/a-sadegh63/vba-mysql-module) to connect VBA to MYSQL